# Python - Search for specific symbols in the inputted text

Tags: python, python-3.x

The challenge is to create a program that will count and print all codes in format "AA000" that contains letters "AB" at the start and "00" at the end of the code.

```
def main():
    code = list(input ("Please enter all codes of your products in format 'AA000':").split())
    print("Your codes are:", code)

    char = -1
    for char_pos in range(len(code)):
        if code[char_pos] == "AB" or code[char_pos] == "00":
            char = char_pos
            print("ok")
    if char == -1:
        print("No!")


main()


==================================================================================================

    Please enter all codes of your products in format 'AA000':00
    Your codes are: ['00']
    ok

==================================================================================================

    Please enter all codes of your products in format 'AA000':AB400
    Your codes are: ['AB400']
    No!
```

It doesn't work as planned because program cant find those symbols while they are entered together, but separetly "AB" and "00" program can find... How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need to use loops, just check if `len(code) == 5 and code.startswith('AB') and code.endswith('00')`.

Comment: Using a regular expression `bool(re.match(r'AB\d00'))` will be more concise, but the condition above does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing to check that each part of the code conforms to the filter:

```
def main():
    code = input("Please enter all codes of your products in format 'AA000':")
    print("Your codes are:", code)
        
    if len(code) == 5 and code[:2] == 'AB' and code[-2:] == '00':
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("No!")


main()
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tested it and it's working! But there another problem raised. I should assign those codes that contain "AB" and "00" at the end to the variable to count and print them. How can I assign it properly?